# What should I say for "I like it now"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm wondering what to say if I were to say:

> I didn't like it before (I believe it should be すきじゃなかったでも..., but I may be wrong, but I like it now.

Some context on the usage: I'm writing this assignment about moving school; and I don't know what to use.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it that you've come to like? A movie? Food? Something else?

Comment: I am talking about moving schools.

Comment: In that case, you could also use the verb 慣{な}れる (to get used to) or the expression 平気{へいき}だ (I'm fine, I'm alright). It's more neutral than "I like" but it might fit better for what you're describing.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

You can say either

> [好]{す}きになった。

or

> [今]{いま}は[好]{す}きだ。

[好]{す}きに in the first sentence is the adverbial form of the な-adjective [好]{す}き, and なる is a verb that means “to become”. It is closer in construction to “I have become fond of it” than to “I like it now”.

The second sentence is a more literal translation of “I like it now”.

I used the plain style above (because you did in すきじゃなかった). If you prefer the です/ます-style, you would have to modify the ending of the sentences.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me.